# 2.2 Pipeline deployment

Tags: magento2.2, repository, static-content-deploy

I was reading on the new Pipeline deployment [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/deployment/pipeline/technical-details.html) but I don't understand how this is supposed to work in a repository.

In developer mode static content is dynamic, but if the build system commits it then it won't work anymore after the first time.

Also if the build system pulls changes, generates and then commits the repository will be a mess where every second commit is a "generate static content". I am probably missing something.

Comment: I have the same question. The docs do not explain how to set up the repositories at all. They imply 1 repository, but does this mean you have different branches or somehow ignore different directories on dev, prod, etc.? confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You should not commit generated files (pub/static,generated,...) into your repository from developer machine.

If you want to keep your generated files in your git repository, you can commit them only for repository tags (for example release0.0.1), not branches.

Or you can "package" these generated files into the docker image.